# Python code to find the radius of each star in a fits file

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I am trying to write a program that takes a fits file and gives the coordinates and radius of every star in the array. So far I have been able to find the coordinates, but I am having trouble finding the radius. Below is what I have so far. Thanks!

```
import pyfits
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import scipy.ndimage as snd
import csv
import astropy.table
import astropy.units as u


#set a variable equal to your file#
data_path="cor_Data_0000.fits"

hdulist=pyfits.open(data_path) * 1

dataset=hdulist[0].data * 1
header=hdulist[0].header

#create mask#
mask=dataset * 1

#make mask field all 0s#
mask=np.multiply(mask,0.0)

thrs=0.009

#define x and y values#
y_size=len(dataset)
x_size=len(dataset[0])

#for loop to define each pixel in the mask as either 1 or 0, depending on whether its luminosity#
#is higher or lower than the threshold#

for y in range(y_size):
    for x in range(x_size):
        if dataset[y,x] > thrs:
            mask[y,x]=1


#export the resultant mask as a fits file#

output_path="output0000.fits"
datamatrix = mask * 1
pyfits.writeto(output_path,datamatrix)

#labels where each pixel above the threshold#
labels, num=snd.label(mask, np.ones((3,3)))

#defines the center of mass for each star#
centers = snd.center_of_mass(mask,labels,range(1,num+1))

#defines the x and y values of each center of mass#
x = np.array(centers)[:,0]
y = np.array(centers)[:,1]

#combines these into a y,x table#
coordinates = zip(y,x)

#save the table as a csv file#
outfile=open('coordinates.csv','w')
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
for row in coordinates:
    writer.writerow(row)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: There is *no* information here about even the data, much less the calculation, involved in finding radii.  Without those, code would be a pipe dream.

Comment: What is a fits file?